# How to mock an attr.ib validator

Tags: python, mocking, python-attrs

I have an attrs class:

```
@attr.s    
class Example:
    my_int = attr.ib(validator=attr.validator.instance_of(MyComplexType))
```

I need to mock this validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everything after initialization is baked and immutable, mocking is not gonna work I think.  However you you can temporarily disable validators using [`attr.set_run_validators()`](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.set_run_validators).

Answer (score 1):

You might try subclassing `Example` and overriding `my_int` with your mock validator, assuming you can control the instantiation of the object from your test.